# How to do I convert a full dynamic ASP.NET website to WordPress?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

I have asp.net dynamic website, 
How to do I convert a full to WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. These two types of websites are totally diferent and are not convertable.